# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "+" when expecting one of the following: (

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
declare 
    i number;
    sum number;
begin
    i:=1;
    sum:=0;
    
    for i in 1..100 loop
        if MOD(i,2) != 0 then
            sum:= sum + i;
             dbms_output.put_line(i);
        end if;
    end loop;
    dbms_output.Put_line(sum);
end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sum` is a reserved word, reserved for built-in function. Rename variable to `v_sum` (for example).

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL>
SQL> DECLARE
  2     v_sum  NUMBER;
  3  BEGIN
  4     v_sum := 0;
  5     FOR i IN 1 .. 100 LOOP
  6        IF MOD (i, 2) != 0 THEN
  7           v_sum := v_sum + i;
  8           -- DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (i);
  9        END IF;
 10     END LOOP;
 11     DBMS_OUTPUT.Put_line (v_sum);
 12  END;
 13  /
2500

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Is it a PL/SQL reserved word, or regular Oracle SQL reserved word?

Comment: It is a **reserved** word in PL/SQL, and **key word** in "general" Oracle usage (so SUM can be used as e.g. column name), @jarlh.

Comment: I'd remove the unused `i` variable from lines 2 and 5. The code only uses the other one that appears at line 8.

Comment: Certainly; didn't pay attention. Thank you, @William, fixed.